# Using sshpass and date command with date conversions and variables

Tags: bash

I am writing a script to fix an issue where a hardware component will, for whatever reason, have a different time than another hardware component from time to time.  One component, if not synchronized, will prevent multiple other pieces from synchronizing as well.  That component only uses the UTC timezone, while my customer uses GMT.

My code, in testing, works until I try to pass that to sshpass.  I've tried using backslashes to escape, but the syntax for date seems pretty rigid.

```
[Expert@FWIRND14-ch01-01 ACTIVE]# timeZone=$(grep -i timezone  /config/active | cut -c 10-30); 
echo $timeZone; dateDate=$(date +"%Y")-$(date +"%m")-$(date +"%d");
echo $dateDate; dateTime=$(date +"%T"); echo $dateTime; 
date --date="TZ=\"$timeZone\" $dateTime $dateDate";
wholeEnchilada="TZ="\"$timeZone\"" $dateTime $dateDate";
echo $wholeEnchilada; date --date="$wholeEnchilada"
```

```
Etc/GMT

2023-04-17

22:22:29

Mon Apr 17 22:22:29 GMT 2023

TZ="Etc/GMT" 22:22:29 2023-04-17

Mon Apr 17 22:22:29 GMT 2023
```

I'm a little puzzled because the help for date provides this example and that syntax works in my code.  sshpass seems to want me to enclose everything in quotes too.

```
date --help
...
Show the local time for 9AM next Friday on the west coast of the US
  $ date --date='TZ="America/Los_Angeles" 09:00 next Fri'
```

Examples using sshpass:

```
Expert@FWIRND14-ch01-01 ACTIVE]# timeZone=$(grep -i timezone  /config/active | cut -c 10-30); echo $timeZone; dateDate=$(date +"%Y")-$(date +"%m")-$(date +"%d"); echo $dateDate; dateTime=$(date +"%T"); echo $dateTime; date --date="TZ=\"$timeZone\" $dateTime $dateDate"; wholeEnchilada="TZ="\"$timeZone\"" $dateTime $dateDate"; echo $wholeEnchilada; sshpass -p 'admin' ssh admin@cmm date --date='09:00 next Fri'
Etc/GMT
2023-04-17
21:40:54
Mon Apr 17 21:40:54 GMT 2023
TZ="Etc/GMT" 21:40:54 2023-04-17
BusyBox v1.28.1 (2018-04-02 09:48:47 CDT) multi-call binary.

 

Usage: date [OPTIONS] [+FMT] [TIME]

 

Display time (using +FMT), or set time

 

        [-s,--set] TIME Set time to TIME
        -u,--utc        Work in UTC (don't convert to local time)
        -R,--rfc-2822   Output RFC-2822 compliant date string
        -I[SPEC]        Output ISO-8601 compliant date string
                        SPEC='date' (default) for date only,
                        'hours', 'minutes', or 'seconds' for date and
                        time to the indicated precision
        -r,--reference FILE     Display last modification time of FILE
        -d,--date TIME  Display TIME, not 'now'
        -D FMT          Use FMT for -d TIME conversion

 

Recognized TIME formats:
        hh:mm[:ss]
        [YYYY.]MM.DD-hh:mm[:ss]
        YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm[:ss]
        [[[[[YY]YY]MM]DD]hh]mm[.ss]
        'date TIME' form accepts MMDDhhmm[[YY]YY][.ss] instead

[Expert@FWIRND14-ch01-01 ACTIVE]# timeZone=$(grep -i timezone  /config/active | cut -c 10-30); echo $timeZone; dateDate=$(date +"%Y")-$(date +"%m")-$(date +"%d"); echo $dateDate; dateTime=$(date +"%T"); echo $dateTime; date --date="TZ=\"$timeZone\" $dateTime $dateDate"; wholeEnchilada="TZ="\"$timeZone\"" $dateTime $dateDate"; echo $wholeEnchilada;  sshpass -p 'admin' ssh admin@cmm date --date='TZ="America/Los_Angeles" $dateTime $dateDate'
Etc/GMT
2023-04-18
02:24:11
Tue Apr 18 02:24:11 GMT 2023
TZ="Etc/GMT" 02:24:11 2023-04-18
date: invalid date 'TZ=America/Los_Angeles'


[Expert@FWIRND14-ch01-01 ACTIVE]# timeZone=$(grep -i timezone  /config/active | cut -c 10-30); echo $timeZone; dateDate=$(date +"%Y")-$(date +"%m")-$(date +"%d"); echo $dateDate; dateTime=$(date +"%T"); echo $dateTime; date --date="TZ=\"$timeZone\" $dateTime $dateDate"; wholeEnchilada="TZ="\"$timeZone\"" $dateTime $dateDate"; echo $wholeEnchilada;  sshpass -p 'admin' ssh admin@cmm date --date="TZ='America/Los_Angeles' $dateTime $dateDate"
Etc/GMT
2023-04-18
02:24:50
Tue Apr 18 02:24:50 GMT 2023
TZ="Etc/GMT" 02:24:50 2023-04-18
BusyBox v1.28.1 (2018-04-02 09:48:47 CDT) multi-call binary.

Usage: date [OPTIONS] [+FMT] [TIME]

Display time (using +FMT), or set time

        [-s,--set] TIME Set time to TIME
        -u,--utc        Work in UTC (don't convert to local time)
        -R,--rfc-2822   Output RFC-2822 compliant date string
        -I[SPEC]        Output ISO-8601 compliant date string
                        SPEC='date' (default) for date only,
                        'hours', 'minutes', or 'seconds' for date and
                        time to the indicated precision
        -r,--reference FILE     Display last modification time of FILE
        -d,--date TIME  Display TIME, not 'now'
        -D FMT          Use FMT for -d TIME conversion

Recognized TIME formats:
        hh:mm[:ss]
        [YYYY.]MM.DD-hh:mm[:ss]
        YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm[:ss]
        [[[[[YY]YY]MM]DD]hh]mm[.ss]
        'date TIME' form accepts MMDDhhmm[[YY]YY][.ss] instead
[Expert@FWIRND14-ch01-01 ACTIVE]#
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show an example usage of your `date` variables in a call to `ssh localhost`. Good luck.

Comment: You may be able to replace `dateDate=$(date +"%Y")-$(date +"%m")-$(date +"%d")` with a single `dateDate=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")`

Comment: Thanks!  That does work to make the code less verbode, but I believe the issue is that sshpass wants me to use syntax requiring both double-quotes and single quotes.